# Como sumar con separador de miles y decimales en footer de una tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc

por favor me podrán apoyar con este caso que no puedo resolver y me esta quitando mucho tiempo, el detalle es que no logro que calcule la suma o total de la columna 10 de la tabla Tot. Venta con el separador de miles y decimales lo he intentado de muchas formas pero no tuve éxito. Solo me suma 119.00 lo cual debe ser: 120,036.50
Mis códigos lo puse como imagen porque no puedo subir en los enlaces me sales a cada rato error

```js
function calsum() {  
    var ArtIte = 0; var ArtCan = 0; var CotVta = 0; var TotPlb = 0; var TotPkg = 0;
    $("#tabCot tbody tr").each(function () {
        ArtIte++;
        ArtCan = parseInt($(this).find("td").eq(8).html()) + ArtCan;
        /*CotVta = parseFloat($(this).find("td").eq(10).html().toString().replace(',', '.')) + CotVta;*/
        CotVta += parseFloat($(this).find("td").eq(10).html().replace(',', ''));
        TotPlb = parseFloat($(this).find("td").eq(12).html()) + TotPlb;
        TotPkg = parseFloat($(this).find("td").eq(14).html()) + TotPkg;
    })

    $("#tabCot tfoot tr").first().find("td").eq(0).html(ArtIte);
    $("#tabCot tfoot tr").first().find("td").eq(8).html(ArtCan);
    $("#tabCot tfoot tr").first().find("td").eq(10).html(CotVta.toLocaleString(undefined, { useGrouping: true, minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));
    /*$("#tabCot tfoot tr").first().find("td").eq(10).html(CotVta.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));*/
   /* $("#tabCot tfoot tr").first().find("td").eq(10).html(CotVta.toFixed(2).toString().replace('.', ','));*/
    $("#tabCot tfoot tr").first().find("td").eq(12).html(TotPlb.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
    $("#tabCot tfoot tr").first().find("td").eq(14).html(TotPkg.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
    sumtot()
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Willian, por favor, presioná [edit] y agrega el código de la función `calsum()` que aparentemente sería donde haces las sumas, no?

Comment: Hola Marco, edite y agregue la funcion calsum(), por favor si me indicas como lo hago porque estoy un poco confundido.

Comment: Gracias Marco por tu ayuda, ya pude resolver el problema era cambiar tus indicaciones y en la parte = toLocaleString(undefined, colocar el idioma de la region.

Answer (score 0):

lo que tienes en las columnas no son números son textos y para que se interpreten de manera correcta debes eliminar las comas (",") del texto y todo lo demás es trivial

```js
const valoresColumnas = ["101,317.50", "3,125.00", "15,780.00"]

let sumaTotal = 0;

valoresColumnas.forEach(value => {
   sumaTotal+= parseFloat(value.replace(',', ''));
});

console.log(sumaTotal)
//para el formato que deseas
console.log(sumaTotal.toLocaleString(undefined,{useGrouping: true, minimumFractionDigits: 2}));
```